# How to service a 1995 Schwinn Phantom Coaster Brake hub?

Tags: brakes, hub, coaster

I have a 1995 Schwinn Phantom beach cruiser with a coaster brake that I'd like to service. The coaster brake is staring to feel sloppy and hasn't been looked at in a long time.

- What tools will I need?
- What are the steps to service it?

Comment: What model hub does it have?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is an exact match, but it should get you pretty close:

[Park Tools: Coaster Brake Hub Overhaul](http://www.parktool.com/repair/readhowto.asp?id=104)

Comment: Lol! These days, we would say *link only answers should be updated to summarize the linked page, in case the link dies*. Amazingly, the link still works!